# How to keep previous row while removing duplicate from R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

DF1

```
T1  ID   Type
1   A    L
2   B    Y
3   C    B
4   D    U
5   E    Z
```

DF2

```
T1  ID   Type
1   A    L
2   B    Y
3   F    K
4   G    I
5   H    T
```

Now i want to merge `DF1` and `DF2` but every row should be unique in `New_Data` based on `ID` coloumn of both the data frame.

Required Dataframe:

New_Data

```
T1  ID   Type
1   A    L
2   B    Y
3   C    B
4   D    U
5   E    Z
3   F    K
4   G    I
5   H    T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row bind the two data frames, then drop duplicates based on `ID` column or `ID` + `Type` columns (duplicated rows based on id columns from later data frames in `bind_rows` will be dropped):

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% distinct(ID, Type, .keep_all = T)

#  T1 ID Type
#1  1  A    L
#2  2  B    Y
#3  3  C    B
#4  4  D    U
#5  5  E    Z
#6  3  F    K
#7  4  G    I
#8  5  H    T
```

Based on `ID` column only:

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = T)

#  T1 ID Type
#1  1  A    L
#2  2  B    Y
#3  3  C    B
#4  4  D    U
#5  5  E    Z
#6  3  F    K
#7  4  G    I
#8  5  H    T
```

Comment: It gives me error that numeric column can't be convert into factor.

Comment: The data type of your actual data frames don't match. Can you check `sapply(DF, class)` for both data frames?

Comment: Yes its not matching in both the dataframe.

Comment: `bind_rows` throws errors when it considers the implicit data type conversions to be problematic. If you can bear with potential data loss, replace `bind_rows` with `rbind` should work. `rbind(df1, df2) %>% distinct(ID, Type, .keep_all = T)`. Otherwise you'll have to clean up your data frames to make sure they have the same data types before bind them, and also convert factor column to character columns to avoid warning messages.

Comment: What type of data loss there would be??

Comment: Mostly a string in a numeric column will be `NA`.

Comment: Since i have same columns in Both the dataframe, is there any way to replicate same class for second dataframe as first.??

Comment: *Plan* beforehand what columns types you need in the result. Then convert both data frames' data types to your desired types before binding them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use

```
unique(rbind(DF1,DF2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but to combine the dataframes, you can use the `merge` function:

```
# merge two data frames by ID
New_Data <- merge(DF1, DF2 ,by="ID", all=TRUE)
```

The "all" parameter just means that for all IDs in DF1 and all IDs in DF2 there will be a row in New_Data. However, the merge should not duplicate rows. For further information, I suggest looking up inner and outer joins as well as the documentation for the merge function.

Here are some links:

- [joins diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMKKt.jpg)
- [docs 1](https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html)
- [docs 2](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/merge)

Edit: Binding the rows will also work if you don't want to deal with merging. Row binds performs a vertical stacking of one dataframe on top of the other. To order the stacked data alphabetically, you could try:

```
New_Data <- unique(rbind( DF1, DF2))
New_Data <-  New_Data[order(ID),]
```

Comment: I want to append the two dataframe.